# Make iPhone 5 Layout Completely Independent

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uistoryboard, iphone-5

I'm using a Storyboard for my app and I'm trying to make it iPhone 5-compatible. However, enabling Auto-Layout messes everything up - frame changes later in the code don't work and so on... Is there any way I can make the iPhone 5 layout completely independent from the old iPhone 4-and-below layout (like create a separate storyboard just for the iPhone 5)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "frame changes later in the code don't work and so on" - Using auto layout means using constraints to layout your interface instead of frame changes. Instead of describing the exact position of every object, you describe things like the spacing between objects, or how objects align to each other. You definitely can't just flip the switch on auto layout and expect old manual layout code to work. It has to be updated too.

Comment: @JonHess Yeah, I realize that - that was just an example. Anyway, I decided to in the end go with auto-layout and instead defined a width constraint to change later on. It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to use the autolayout provided by apple, you could check for screensize of the device. Here's a macro from another post at stackoverflow

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

With that macro, you could build a separate storyboard for the iPhone 5 only, and initialize it in your AppDelegate with this

```
NSString *storyboardName;
if (IS_IPHONE_5)
    storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard_iPhone5";
else storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard_iPhone";
storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
```